# Can't connect PC to an Asterisk Server (IP)

Tags: ping, asterisk, external-ip

I have to connect an external network to an Asterisk Server who is available with an external IP. I tried to ping the server from the network but it's not working.

Meanwhile, it's working for every others network I tried, which means the problem must come from the network/router/provider
I have already tried to disable the firewall.

Do you guys have any solutions ? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried looking/asking in the Asterisk community? https://community.asterisk.org/

Comment: This one might help you (Config file) https://community.asterisk.org/t/cannot-connect-to-the-server-please-check/41350

Comment: Could you do some other checks, for example to telnet to a port that should be open? It might be that icmp is blocked somewhere along the way...

Comment: @g_bor I checked a Telnet to the ip adress with Port 22 and it worked. whats wrong?

Comment: It seems that imcp traffic is blocked. I believe that something else is causing the porblem, but this shows why ping is not working.